# Core Animation Requirements

Tags: macos, core-animation, requirements

I've been using NSViewAnimation for some time now and I've read somewhere that Core Animation actually obsoletes it if I target 10.5 or higher. But does every Mac capable of running 10.5 or higher also support Core Animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every mac running Leopard (10.5) supports Core Animation.

Comment: That's a quick answer! Thanks!